# Why doesn't width: 100% apply to local dom hosting element?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, shady-dom

In this custom element, the `width: 90%` will not apply when used in `:host`, but the `width: 90%` will apply if I apply it to `section`. Why is this? Isn't `portfolio-display` a shady dom element in which the `width: 90%` should apply as it's the hosting element instead of `section`?

```
<dom-module id="portfolio-display">
  <style>
    :host {
      height: 60%;
      transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-out;
     }

     section {
       width: 90%;
       background-color: #5a7785;
     }


    .big {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    } 
  </style>

  <template>
    <section>
      <div onclick="page('/portfolio')"
        class="vertical layout">
        <div>
```

Comment: It could be the use of the layouts on the :host that prevent the width from being applied. It could also be how it's used. More information may be necessary.

Comment: Naw, the it was the same without the layout attributes.

Comment: Could you provide implementation example of the component where it fails?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing `display: block;` on your `:host`.

`section` works 'cause most browsers display `section` elements with

```
section { 
    display: block;
}
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cwaPluGurFUQibY760du?p=preview) for an example.

Comment: It's the same with `background-color: #5a7785;` also, though. In addition, the behavior exists if I use layout attributes, which would  make display `flex` I believe.

Comment: Hmm, not sure exactly what you mean, did you see the plunker I linked? Show some more code and I will have a look.

Comment: I've learned the Plunkers are rarely useful because of discrepancies between versions of Polymer elements. For instance, on your Plunkr I can set the `background-color: red` in `:host`. This is not the same behavior on my local Polymer, which `background-color` has no effect on the `:host` for this custom element.

Comment: I can guarantee you it's got nothing to do with dependencies. Most likely, assuming display: block already applied, you don't see the colour because the the height/width of the element's parent is not defined.